# Azure Maps SDK popup does not open after initial load

Tags: javascript, blazor, azure-maps

I am using Azure Maps SDK in a Blazor Server app which uses JavaScript interop. The map works well and renders perfectly.

On initial load of the map component the popup displays correctly when clicking a pin on the map. However, when the data source changes via an API call `datasource.importDataFromUrl(organisationDataFeed);` it correctly brings back the filtered data, but when I click on one of the pins again the popup does not display. The click event handler (for the pin) is being called, but the popup does not open.

```
(function () {

    var map, datasource, popup;

    // Global export
    window.azuremaps = {
        initMap: function (organisationDataFeed) {
            // Create an instance of the map control and set some options.

            map = new atlas.Map('map', {
                // center: [-97, 39],

                // center: [18.424095, -33.925000],
                center: [26.157981, -29.083937],
                zoom: 4,
                pitch: 50,
                style: 'night',
                view: 'Auto',

                // Add your Azure Maps subscription key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: ''
                }
            });

            map.controls.add([
                new atlas.control.ZoomControl(),
                new atlas.control.CompassControl(),
                new atlas.control.PitchControl(),
                new atlas.control.StyleControl()
            ], {
                position: "top-right"
            });

            // Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {

                // Create a data source and add it to the map.
                datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource(null, {
                    //Tell the data source to cluster point data.
                    cluster: true,

                    //The radius in pixels to cluster points together.
                    clusterRadius: 45,

                    // The maximium zoom level in which clustering occurs.
                    // If you zoom in more than this, all points are rendered as symbols.
                    clusterMaxZoom: 15
                });
                map.sources.add(datasource);

                //Create a bubble layer for rendering clustered data points.
                var clusterBubbleLayer = new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(datasource, null, {
                    //Scale the size of the clustered bubble based on the number of points inthe cluster.
                    radius: [
                        'step',
                        ['get', 'point_count'],
                        20,         //Default of 20 pixel radius.
                        100, 30,    //If point_count >= 100, radius is 30 pixels.
                        750, 40     //If point_count >= 750, radius is 40 pixels.
                    ],

                    //Change the color of the cluster based on the value on the point_cluster property of the cluster.
                    color: [
                        'step',
                        ['get', 'point_count'],
                        'rgba(0,255,0,0.8)',            //Default to green. 
                        100, 'rgba(255,255,0,0.8)',     //If the point_count >= 100, color is yellow.
                        750, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)'        //If the point_count >= 100, color is red.
                    ],
                    strokeWidth: 0,
                    filter: ['has', 'point_count'] //Only rendered data points which have a point_count property, which clusters do.
                });

                //Add a click event to the layer so we can zoom in when a user clicks a cluster.
                map.events.add('click', clusterBubbleLayer, clusterClicked);

                //Add mouse events to change the mouse cursor when hovering over a cluster.
                map.events.add('mouseenter', clusterBubbleLayer, function () {
                    map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'pointer';
                });

                map.events.add('mouseleave', clusterBubbleLayer, function () {
                    map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'grab';
                });

                // Create a layer to render the individual locations.
                var individualSymbolLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                    filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']], //Filter out clustered points from this layer.

                    textOptions: {
                        textField: ['get', 'name'],
                        color: "#FFFFFF",
                        offset: [0, -2.2]
                    },
                });

                map.events.add('click', individualSymbolLayer, symbolClicked);

                //Add the clusterBubbleLayer and two additional layers to the map.
                map.layers.add([
                    clusterBubbleLayer,

                    // Create a symbol layer to render the count of locations in a cluster.
                    new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                        iconOptions: {
                            image: 'none' //Hide the icon image.
                        },
                        textOptions: {
                            textField: ['get', 'point_count_abbreviated'],
                            offset: [0, 0.4]
                        }
                    }),

                    individualSymbolLayer
                    
                ]);

                // Create a popup but leave it closed so we can update it and display it later.
                popup = new atlas.Popup({
                    pixelOffset: [0, -18],
                    closeButton: true
                });

                // Retrieve a GeoJSON data set and add it to the data source. 
                datasource.importDataFromUrl(organisationDataFeed);
            });
        },
    };

    function clusterClicked(e) {
        if (e && e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0 && e.shapes[0].properties.cluster) {
            // Get the clustered point from the event.
            var cluster = e.shapes[0];

            // Get the cluster expansion zoom level. This is the zoom level at which the cluster starts to break apart.
            datasource.getClusterExpansionZoom(cluster.properties.cluster_id).then(function (zoom) {

                //Update the map camera to be centered over the cluster. 
                map.setCamera({
                    center: cluster.geometry.coordinates,
                    zoom: zoom + 2,
                    type: 'ease',
                    duration: 200
                });
            });
        }
    }

    function symbolClicked(e) {
        // Make sure the event occured on a point feature.
        
        var popupTemplate = '<div class="card border-success" style="visibility: visible"><div class="card-header" style="visibility: visible">{name}</div><div class="card-body text-success" style="visibility: visible"><h5 class="card-title" style="visibility: visible">{description}</h5><p class="card-text" style="visibility: visible">Contact: {contact}</p><p class="card-text">Web: {website}</p></div></div>';

        if (e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0) {
            var content, coordinate;

            // Check to see if the first value in the shapes array is a Point Shape.
            if (e.shapes[0] instanceof atlas.Shape && e.shapes[0].getType() === 'Point') {
                var properties = e.shapes[0].getProperties();
                content = popupTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, properties.name).replace(/{description}/g, properties.description).replace(/{contact}/g, properties.contact).replace(/{website}/g, properties.website);
                coordinate = e.shapes[0].getCoordinates();
            }
            else if (e.shapes[0].type === 'Feature' && e.shapes[0].geometry.type === 'Point') {

                // Check to see if the feature is a cluster.
                if (e.shapes[0].properties.cluster) {
                    content = '<div style="padding:10px;">Cluster of ' + e.shapes[0].properties.point_count + ' symbols</div>';
                } else {
                    // Feature is likely from a VectorTileSource.
                    content = popupTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, properties.name).replace(/{description}/g, properties.description).replace(/{contact}/g, properties.contact).replace(/{website}/g, properties.website);
                }

                coordinate = e.shapes[0].geometry.coordinates;
            }
            
            if (content && coordinate) {
                // Populate the popupTemplate with data from the clicked point feature.

                console.log("JB content");
                console.log(content);

                console.log("JB coordinate");
                console.log(coordinate);

                popup.setOptions({
                    //Update the content of the popup.
                    content: content,

                    //Update the position of the popup with the symbols coordinate.
                    position: coordinate
                });

                console.log("JB: logging map variable");
                console.log(map);

                popup.open(map);
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

*content* and *coordinate* are populated with values and evaluate to true, the options are correctly set, but just the last line: `popup.open(map);` does not work if the data source changes bringing back new data into the map. It works perfectly on initial load.

Any ideas what I could do to get this working? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code where the binding for the popup is done?

Comment: @Umair this is the code that gets called from Blazor to initialize the map. It works. The popup template is in function symbolClicked(e)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

- Double check the values of coordinate and content. The coordinates should be an array with [longitude,latitude] numbers (make sure they aren't string values of numbers). The content should either be a DOMElement (i.e. div), or a string. If it is anything else, it may not display anything.
- Double check the "map" variable is a map the second time around. If the reference is lost for some reason, that function won't work.
- It looks like you are create a new popup all the time. Often apps only want to display a single popup at a time. In that case it is more efficient to create a single popup and reuse it as shown in this example: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Reusing%20Popup%20with%20Multiple%20Pins

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is much appreciated. 1. So content is a div (see my updated post above where I create the popuptemplate). 2. The coordinates come back as numbers in an array. I checked in the browser console. 3. Yes the map reference is still a reference.

Comment: I noticed that when I open the popup after the initial load then open it up again after a subsequent load it does not display. However, if I load the map once then change the search filters and reload the map a second or third time then the popup opens. It only does not work if I opened it then perform a second reload/re-render of the map component.

Comment: Also I notice that the popup is still in the DOM it just seems invisible. So I added an inline CSS style="visibility: visible" to all the div elements and it still does not show. Does the map element hide the popup when one closes it? Maybe it is setting a CSS style to hidden somewhere? Not sure where to look if this might be the case

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me in your code, it looks fine. You shouldn't need to add visibilty to your divs. The popup class wraps your content with a div and sets the visibility on there. If the popup div when inspecting DOM is still saying hidden for visibility, then either the open function isn't being called, or the close function it being called somewhere. Only other thing I can think of at the moment is possibly some CSS in your app that is causing the rendering issue somehow. Try manually changing the visibility using the browser dev tools to see if the new content is there.

Comment: Okay cool thanks. Let me investigate this further taking your suggestion into account.